# "sit back and relax" vs. "kick back and relax"?

Tags: expressions, slang, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why 'kick back' can mean 'get relaxed'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/why-kick-back-can-mean-get-relaxed)

I have seen so many times "Sit back and relax" while installing softwares. I understand that it means it will take a while to install.

Today I saw "Kick back and relax" while installing the following software. What does it mean? Is this slang?

Image:
[image]

Comment: To "kick back and relax" is somewhat stronger than the other phrase. It implies a more, shall we say, *energetic* form of relaxation. Or at least going at it more avidly. One thinks of alcohol consumed, carnal pursuits undertaken, conversation and laughter, everything done with gusto — even mere laziness is taken up a notch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OED, **kick back** is an informal way to say **relax or be at leisure**.

Comment: Do you disagree with the votes to close as a dup? I don't think you should answer questions that are obviously duplicates - it just clutters up the site. If you think your answer is worth giving, you should post it against the original (as I've just done), not here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- No, I don't.  And I will do that henceforth.  But if it's about cluttering, why don't we delete the question altogether, instead of closing it?

Comment: Opinions may differ, but I think as a rule dups should *not* be deleted. They won't have exactly the same title or question text indexed, so keeping them increases the chances that a new "asker" will find the dup instead of posting yet another one on the same topic. I just think we don't want to smear **Answers** across multiple pages, but multiple "redirects" to the same page with *the best answer* are a positive benefit, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I am not sure, but if you think it helps, I will delete my answer?

Comment: As I've said before, I'm only one voice here, so don't delete it on my account. Also bear in mind that if you do, newer users with lower rep won't be able to see it, so they'll be denied access to any wisdom contained in these comments! As it happens, having considered the matter carefully I decided that - good as it was - Kosmonaut's answer to the original wasn't definitive (though I'll probably have a long wait before mine collects enough upvotes to topple it!). Yours here certainly isn't *wrong*, but it probably adds nothing to the others, so if I were you I'd leave it here, not move it.