# What does "I'd kick it with who I wanted" mean in these lyrics?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

> If I Were a Boy
>
> (...)
>   And throw on what I wanted and go
>   Drink beer with the guys
>   and chase after girls
>   **I'd kick it with who I wanted
>
>   and I'd never get confronted for it**
>   'cause they'd stick up for me
>   if I were a boy
>   I think I could understand

“I'd kick it with who I wanted
And I'd never get confronted for it”

What's the meaning of these lyrics? What does the 'it' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Kicking it" is slang and is equivalent to "hanging out" or "chilling out" - [see slang dictionary here.](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/kick-it)

The origin of this slang phrase is probably related to "kicking back" - [see previous question on this.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/why-can-kick-back-mean-get-relaxed)

So the song lyric you mention means something along the lines of *"I'll hang out with anyone I want to, and no-one is going to challenge me.".*

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of American lingo, it could be translated as:  "I would associate (be with, enjoy the company of) with whomever I wanted to, and no one would complain.